# Cannot find the Amazon redirected url in the BeautifulSoup (Python). Any idea from where to get the redirect url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to get the Amazon advertising data using the Amazon Advertising API.
I have to open a specific link: "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=...&scope=cpc_advertising:campaign_management&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://.../"
, that redirects me to an url where I can give my Login data.

To get that redirect url, I am using the BeautifulSoup in Python. In the Web Inspector I see that the redirect url is in the response headers under the name "location", yet when called with the BeautifulSoup, the "location" is missing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Thats the User Agent I get from the Web Inspector'}

p = requests.get(
    'Thats the link from which I wll be further redirected')

login_data = {
    'appAction': 'SIGNIN',
    'email': '...',
    'password': '...'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = p.url
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    login_data['appActionToken'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'appActionToken'})['value']
    login_data['openid.return_to'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'openid.return_to'})['value']
    login_data['prevRID'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'prevRID'})['value']
    login_data['workflowState'] = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'workflowState'})['value']
    r = s.post(url, data = login_data, headers=headers)


    print(r.content)
```

Any ideas from where we can get the redirect urls ?

Answer (score 0):

Youself are the master of your application. You have to know the redirect url for your application and set it in the Login-with-Amazon console.
You can set multiple redirect urls for each application in the console.

Something like:

```
https://www.yourpage.com/login
http://localhost:8080/login
```

See also:
https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/setting-up/generate-api-tokens